При запуске wireguard зависает SSH подключение и не позволяет подключаться к серверу
Купил я значит два сервера(Debian 11) и решил поднять wireguard на них и соединить их, читал разные статьи, спрашивал у гпт, все хорошо, но вот незадача, в статьях говориться указывать в Address[Interface] 10.0.0.1/24, и AllowedIPs[Peer] 10.0.0.2/32, а на клиенте 0.0.0.0/0, но если я так указываю и стартую wireguard, ssh подключение зависает и затем наотрез отказывается подключаться к серверу, я попробовал посмотреть через ifconfig айпишник сервера, а там вместо знакомого 10.x.x.x айпи адрес самого сервера(ну то есть который выдали при покупке), тогда я решил указать в Address 0.0.0.0 и в AllowedIPs 0.0.0.0, и оно работает, но говорят это не очень хорошо, так как быть? Может кто нибудь сможет рассказать как же все таки грамотно настроить конфигурацию и для сервера и для клиента , спасибо)
